# Can I assign variables in batch?

Tags: r

For example I have 2 variables `a` and `b` (actually more than 2 in my real case), can I assign values for them in a way like `c(a,b)<-c(0,0)`, just like the *Tuple* in Python? Thank you.

Comment: @JackManey Yes I tried but didn't get through. I am asking ways of assignment with the same effect.

Comment: If you want to assign them to all be the same value (i.e. 0 in your example), you can do `a = b = 0`. But there isn't an equivalent to tuple unpacking in R.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519790/assign-multiple-new-variables-in-a-single-line-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built in way to do it - what you're looking for is very similar to `lists` and `vectors` in `R` - instead of calling back `a`, `b`, and `c`, you call back `a[1]`, `a[2]`, and `a[3]`. If it's important for you to be able to call back this values by separate names, and to be able to assign them from the same line, you can make a simple function:

```
Assign <- function(Names, Values) {
             for(i in 1:length(Names)){
                  assign(Names[i], Values[i], envir=.GlobalEnv)
             }}

>A <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
>B <- c(0,4,2,3)
>Assign(A,B)
>c
#[1] 2
```

I couldn't figure out a way for the `apply` family to tackle this one without making it too complicated - maybe someone could help me out.

Comment: `Assign <- function(Names, Values) {sapply(seq_along(Names), function(i){assign(Names[i], Values[i], envir=.GlobalEnv)});invisible()}` Not too terribly complicated - just use `sapply` or `lapply` on a vector of the indices and create an anonymous function to do the actual assignment.  I put the invisible in there to make it a little nicer.

Comment: Thanks - I've never tried `seq_along` before - seems like a good alternative for a task that really needs a `for` loop but is susceptible to the disadvantages that come along with loops.

Comment: or `mapply(assign, Names, Values, MoreArgs = list(envir = .GlobalEnv))`

Comment: @flodel Much better - I need to think about `mapply` more often

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%=%` as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519790/assign-multiple-new-variables-in-a-single-line-in-r/13353585#13353585)
*(you have to copy and paste the four functions)*

```
# Example Call;  Note the use of g()  AND  `%=%`
#     Right-hand side can be a list or vector
g(a, b, c)  %=%  list("hello", 123, list("apples, oranges"))

# Results: 
> a
[1] "hello"
> b
[1] 123
> c
[[1]]
[1] "apples, oranges"
```

Comment: Thanks for the link - looks like this question should probably be closed as a duplicate.