# Why can't I assign to multiple variables using mapply/assign?

Tags: r, destructuring

(As an exercise) I was trying to emulate some languages such as perl, etc by assigning to multiple variables in R.

```
my ($a, $b, $c) = ( 1, 2, 3 );
```

now $a is 1, $b is 2, $c is 3.

I expected this to work:

```
mapply(assign, c('A', 'B', 'C'), 1:3)
```

But it just returned a named int vector of 1,2,3.

Why didn't this work as expected?

Edit: First part of my question was indeed a duplicate of: [Assign multiple new variables on LHS in a single line in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519790/assign-multiple-new-variables-in-a-single-line-in-r) but would still like to know why my approach of mapply/assign didn't work.

Comment: `mapply` doesn't work because it will always collect the results into a single object. (and the assignment is by default taking place in the current environment, not the global one)

Comment: ...for instance, `mapply(assign, x = c('A', 'B', 'C'), value = 1:3,MoreArgs = list(envir = .GlobalEnv))` would have worked, but will also return the single object you saw before.

Comment: The "why" part of your question is also answered at the duplicate, as several of those answers use the same assign/mapply strategy as you, the only difference being that they took care to specify the correct environment for the assignment. I added the comments above in order to be sure that that was clear.

Comment: Ah...thanks! I missed your comments on this question, apologies.