# How to assign multiple values as once in R?

Tags: r

Is there an already existing method of assigning each of those `data.frame` objects to separate variables?

```
list(cyl4, cyl6, cyl8) <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
```

> Error in list(x, y, z) <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl) : 
>     could not find function "list<-

Comment: You can name the list elements i.e. `lst <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl); names(lst) <- paste0('dat', seq_along(lst))` and use `list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)`  But, I would recommend to work with list instead of having multiple objects in the global environment

Comment: Do you really *need* them to be in their own variables? Why not use the output from split directly?

Comment: I couldn't believe I was the first person to ask this question. Further Googling turned up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519790/assign-multiple-new-variables-in-a-single-line-in-r. That was an older post though. Maybe something better has appeared since then?

Comment: @Dason: I'm trying to simulate a multi-step process in R, where I do care about intermediate values.

Comment: @wdkrnls I never said get rid of the intermediate values.  But why do they need to be variables and not elements of a list?

Comment: @Dason: I have names in mind for each of the values of the list and may need to iteratively mutate each to solve nonlinear relationships between each data frame.

Comment: And why does that mean you can't use a list?

Comment: Sounds like a case of [the XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) (sort of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `assign` to assign a value to variable. The variable names are strings.

In the code below I've looped though the elements of the list and assigned names from the vector `names`.

```
l <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)   

names <- c('cyl4', 'cyl6', 'cyl8')

for (i in 1:length(names)) assign(names[i], l[[i]])
```

Or the `list2env` function as pointed out by @Roland (and others). The `attach` function does something similar.

```
l <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)   

names(l) <- c('cyl4', 'cyl6', 'cyl8')

list2env(l, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Or

```
attach(l)
```

Although, as others have pointed out. This might not be the best idea; it's easier to keep track of things inside lists. You can just access them as need be with `$`.

```
l$cyl4
```

Comment: Better use `list2env` ... But really, the answer is not to do this.

Comment: cool! I'd never seen list2env before, I'll change my answer