# Error in 'colsplit' function?

Tags: r, reshape

Im am trying to split a column of a dataframe into 2 columns using `transform` and `colsplit` from reshape package. I don't get what I am doing wrong. Here's an example...

```
library(reshape)
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c("x-1","y-2","z-3"))
```

Now I am trying to split the `col1` into `col1.a` and `col1.b` at the delimiter '-'. the following is my code...

`df1 <- transform(df1,col1 = colsplit(col1,split='-',names = c('a','b')))`

Now in my RStudio when I do `View(df1)` I do get to see col1.a and col1.b split the way I want to.

But when I run... 
`df1$col1.a` or `head(df1$col1.a)` I get NULL. Apparently I am not able to make any further operations on these split columns. What exactly is wrong with this?

Comment: I am using reshape and not reshape2

Comment: I think it's the argument. It might be `pattern` instead of `split`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`colsplit` returns a list, the easiest (and idiomatic) way to assign these to multiple columns in the data frame is to use `[<-`

eg

```
df1[c('col1.a','col1.b')] <- colsplit(df1$col1,'-',c('a','b'))
```

it will be much harder to do this within transform  (see [Assign multiple new variables on LHS in a single line in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519790/assign-multiple-new-variables-in-a-single-line-in-r))

Comment: Yes this works for me... I didnt get the list output part... thanks... the df$col1['a'] was what I needed, but your way is better