# How can I simultaneously assign value to multiple new columns with R and dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Given

```
base <- data.frame( a = 1) 
f <- function() c(2,3,4)
```

I am looking for a solution that would result in a function `f` being applied to each row of `base` data frame and the result would be appended to each row. Neither of the following works:

```
result <- base %>% rowwise() %>% mutate( c(b,c,d) = f() )
result <- base %>% rowwise() %>% mutate( (b,c,d) = f() )
result <- base %>% rowwise() %>% mutate( b,c,d = f() )
```

What is the correct syntax for this task?

This appears to be a similar problem ([Assign multiple new variables on LHS in a single line in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519790/assign-multiple-new-variables-on-lhs-in-a-single-line-in-r)) but I am specifically interested in solving this with functions from tidyverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best you are going to do is a `do()` to modify the data.frame. Perhaps

```
base %>% do(cbind(., setNames(as.list(f()), c("b","c","d"))))
```

would probably be best if `f()` returned a list in the first place for the different columns.

Comment: Thank you! The complete solution with parameter in f() would be then: `base <- data.frame( a = c(1,2))`   

`f <- function(x) data.frame(b = 2*x, c = 3*x, d= 4*x)`

`base %>% do(cbind(., f(.$a)))`

Comment: In my scenario `rowwise()` was still required before `do` (despite the example solution above works without it).

Answer (score 0):

In case you're willing to do this without dplyr:

```
# starting data frame
base_frame <- data.frame(col_a = 1:10, col_b = 10:19)

# the function you want applied to a given column 
add_to <- function(x) { x + 100 } 

# run this function on your base data frame, specifying the column you want to apply the function to:
add_computed_col <- function(frame, funct, col_choice) {
  frame[paste(floor(runif(1, min=0, max=10000)))] = lapply(frame[col_choice], funct)
  return(frame)
}
```

Usage:

```
df <- add_computed_col(base_frame, add_to, 'col_a')
head(df)
```

[image]

And add as many columns as needed:

```
df_b <- add_computed_col(df, add_to, 'col_b')
head(df_b)
```

[image]

Rename your columns.