# Assigning multiple variables to multiple values at once R?

Tags: r, variables

I want to assign 100 variables to 100 values.
How can I do this?

For example if I want `x1, x2, x3, .... x100` to be assigned with 100 values at once (say `x1 = 5, x2 = "c143", x3 = 0, ....`)

What is the way to do this? Please advise, didn't find a way to do this here/Dr. G.
I have tried lapply/sapply/for loops but maybe there is more easy straight forward way?

Comment: can you please provide a [minimal reporducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. also have a look at [how to write a good R question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3250126).

Comment: Not very clear what you mean maybe something like `setNames(c('A', 'B', 'C'), paste0('x', seq(3)))`?

Comment: I have shown you what I want: you have 100 variables: x1 to x100.
You want to assign all of them with 100 values.

Comment: Further, you are probably looking for a `join` of some kind

Comment: Re: *I have tried lapply/sapply/for loops but maybe there is more easy straight forward way?* Can you please share?

Comment: @Sotos you mean that for simplicity if I have x1, x2, x3 and use your method I will be able to assign them all at once to 1,2,3 for example?

Comment: @Sotos I think you are the closest. Will try it.
I thought I can just do something like c(x1, x2, ..., x100) <- (1, ... , 100)

Comment: If you share what you have tried with your `lapply` etc... so I can see the structure of your output I'd be able to help you further.

Comment: @Sotos What I actualy wanted to do is to assign a vector of variable names to values. Your solution seems to be the best.

Comment: I could be that you mean something like this: `l <- list(x1 = 5, x2 = "dfs"); list2env(l, envir = globalenv())`.

Comment: If `a <- 1:100`, you can do `names(a) <- paste0('x', 1:100)` This will give you a named integer vector, but you won't be able to use that with easy indexing. If you want to be able to do fx `a$52`afterwards, use: `a <- as.list(1:100)` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setNames`, i.e.

```
setNames(c('A', 'B', 'C'), paste0('x', seq(3)))
# x1  x2  x3 
#"A" "B" "C"
```

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you have 100 different names for variables stored as character strings and numeric values stored in a numeric vector, then you can do the following:

```
# vector with names for variables
vars <- c("x1","x2","x3")

# vector with values for variables
vals <- c( 1,2,3)


#check variable list
ls()
# [1] "vals" "vars"

# assign values to variables
for (i in seq(vars)) assign(vars[i],vals[i])

# check variable list
ls()
# [1] "i"    "vals" "vars" "x1"   "x2"   "x3"
```

As suggested in comments there are some other approaches (again depending on how you want to use the variable names):
[Assign multiple new variables on LHS in a single line in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519790/assign-multiple-new-variables-on-lhs-in-a-single-line-in-r)